# How to send xml doc as a byte array to soap service?

Tags: php, .net, xml, web-services, soap

I have an `XML` which i have converted into a `byteArray` using the below `PHP` code:

```
$xmlStr = file_get_contents('demo2.xml'); // read file to string
$byte_array = unpack('C*', $xmlStr); 
echo  implode(',', $byte_array) ;
```

I need to pass the above byte array to the below soap envelope in file tag.
The **backend webservice** has been written in `.net`

```
  <Envelope xmlns="http://example/soap/envelope/">
        <Body>
            <sample  xmlns="http://example.org/">
                <User>[string?]</User>
                <Password>[string?]</Password>
                <File>[anyType?]</File>
            </sample>
        </Body>
    </Envelope>
```

I'm using `wizdler` to make a service call, but I'm ending up in getting the error below:

```
    The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message: There was an error while trying to deserialize parameter  
 The InnerException message was 'Element File from namespace http://example.org/ cannot have child contents to be deserialized as an object. 

Please use XmlNode[] to deserialize this pattern of XML.'.  Please see InnerException for more details.
```

How do i send a `xml` file as **byte array** in the above scenario?

Answer (score 0):

I also was looking for it and i found a solution.
I think you can try it 
[How to send a File(base64Binary) in web service request using SOAP UI ?](https://aswinprasanthblog.wordpress.com/2016/03/21/how-to-send-a-filebase64binary-in-web-service-request-using-soap-ui/)